# Mac Library LaunchAgents folder: Accidently deleted files, causing menu bar to return to foreground every few seconds

Tags: macos, terminal

Originally i was trying to delete the application "Razer Synapse" from my Mac menu bar (which was not working with the usual cmd+click and deleting the app manually) and by accident deleted two plist files in my ~/Library/LaunchAgents Folder.

Now my Mac is almost unusable: Every few seconds the menu bar comes to the "foreground", meaning whatever i do gets interrupted and "greyed out", as if you'd click on something else and my "Razer Synapse" menu bar icon pops up. (Currently i have just two files in my LaunchAgents Folder: "com.google.keystone.agent.plist" and "com.valvesoftware.steamclean.plist", that's it. 
Now i have no idea how to fix this issue. I'd be very thankful for any hint!

edit: This seems also to affect the "Restart" function: When trying to restart my mac, i get a black screen and nothing happens, so i'm forced to hold the Power button.

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable solution (in my case) seems to be the following: Given that the specific application "Razer Synapse" was causing the problem, i reinstalled it and used "Utilities --> Uninstall Razer Synapse", now fortunately the issue is solved.